# How to find matches in an array with objects and change property?

Tags: javascript

When names match in object property "name" I want to change this property to "TV(1)" for the first match and increase a counter for every next match, but it's doesn't work for me (please run code to see the problem), how I can change array with objects regarding that?

```js
const array = [
{name: "TV", price: 12323, id: 321 },
{name: "Kettle", price: 123, id: 1211 },
{name: "TV", price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
{name: "Car", price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
{name: "TV", price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }
]           

const nameIsMatch = (name, id) => {
  let count = 0
  return array.map((item) => {
    const condition = item.name === name && item.id !== id
    const formattedName = `${item.name}(${count += 1})`
    return {
      price: item.price,
      name: condition ? formattedName : item.name,
      id: item.id
    }
  })
}
array.forEach((el) => {
  console.log(nameIsMatch(el.name, el.id))
})
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a detailed technical diagnostic. Does it give you errors? Incorrect output? Eat all of the cheese in your fridge? Help us out by giving us a hint as to where to look.

Comment: Tip: Although the "arrow operator" is cool, this is just a regular function and should be defined as `function nameIsMatch(name, id) {` without any fanfare or ceremony.

Comment: You increment `count` every time instead of only when `condition === true`

Comment: This could be fixed by using a simple `if` instead of all this oddness with computing both paths regardless of outcome and saving that in variables you later ternary decide between.

Comment: @tadman _"...this is just a regular function and should be defined as function nameIsMatch(...) without any fanfare or ceremony"_ - Of course you can objectively prove this statement.

Comment: @Andreas Many editors will recognize `function x(..)` and help you auto-complete, but `const x = (...) => { ... }` is interpreted differently. It's not considered a named function.

Comment: @tadman I should have added a _/s_  Imho your comment is just an opinion and there's no good reason why this could not be an arrow function

Comment: @Andreas I'm not being sarcastic, I'm being 100% serious. Too much JavaScript code devolves into primordial goo because people don't declare simple functions as functions. It makes looking up function definitions utterly infuriating. I can't `git grep "function X"`, I can't use code completion, I can't use a *lot* of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy fix is to just rework a tiny bit of code with the old technique of *moving things around to where they belong*:

```
return array.map((item) => {
  return {
    price: item.price,
    name: (item.name === name && item.id !== id) ? `${item.name}(${count += 1})` : item.name,
    id: item.id
  }
})
```

It's now a bit of a mess due to the ternary, so you could always unwind that a bit:

```
return array.map(item => {
  // Make a copy of `item`
  let i = { ...item };

  // Override if necessary
  if (item.name === name && item.id !== id) {
    i. name = `${item.name}(${count += 1})`;
  }

  return i;
})
```

Where that's not as concise, but it's a lot more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object that keeps a counter for each name.

```js
const array = [
{name: "TV", price: 12323, id: 321 },
{name: "Kettle", price: 123, id: 1211 },
{name: "TV", price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
{name: "Car", price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
{name: "TV", price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }
];

const nameIsMatch = (array) => {
  let counts = {};
  return array.map(({
    name,
    price,
    id
  }) => {
    let count = counts[name] || 1;
    const formattedName = `${name}(${count})`
    counts[name] = count + 1;
    return {
      price,
      name: formattedName,
      id
    }
  })
}

console.log(nameIsMatch(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following code**

```js
const array = [
    {name: "TV", price: 12323, id: 321 },
    {name: "Kettle", price: 123, id: 1211 },
    {name: "TV", price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
    {name: "Car", price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
    {name: "TV", price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }];
    
const hash = {};

array.forEach(function(obj){
    if(!hash[obj.name])
        hash[obj.name] = 1;
    obj.name = `${obj.name}(${hash[obj.name]++})`;
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'TV', price: 12323, id: 321 },
  { name: 'Kettle', price: 123, id: 1211 },
  { name: 'TV', price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
  { name: 'Car', price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
  { name: 'TV', price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 },
];

const tv_array = [];

let count = 1

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let name = array[i].name;
  if (name === 'TV') {
    tv_array.push({
      name: `TV(${count})`,
      price: array[i].price,
      id: array[i].id,
    })
    count++
  } else {
    tv_array.push(array[i]);
  } 
}

console.log(tv_array);
```

Output:

```sh
[
  { name: 'TV(1)', price: 12323, id: 321 },
  { name: 'Kettle', price: 123, id: 1211 },
  { name: 'TV(2)', price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
  { name: 'Car', price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
  { name: 'TV(3)', price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    {name: "TV", price: 12323, id: 321 },
    {name: "Kettle", price: 123, id: 1211 },
    {name: "TV", price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
    {name: "Car", price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
    {name: "TV", price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }];

const result = array.map((data, index) => {
      if(data.name === 'TV') {
              return {...data, name:'TV'+'('+index+')'}
      }
      return data
})

console.info(result)
```

You have to use like this It's working for me as per your output

Answer (score 0):

you could actually do it one by one even though this step will take a lot of time, however this will gives you a better understanding.

Data

```
const array = [
{name: "TV", price: 12323, id: 321 },
{name: "Kettle", price: 123, id: 1211 },
{name: "TV", price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
{name: "Car", price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
{name: "TV", price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }
]
```

function to get all the Data Name. This will return `[ 'TV', 'Kettle', 'Car' ]`

```
function getAllDataName(arr){
  let a = arr.map((dataName) => dataName["name"] )
  let b = []

  a.filter((dataName) => {
    // includes() used to find the intersect of array with particular data
    if(!b.includes(dataName)){
      b.push(dataName)
    }
  })

  return b
}
```

function to map all the Data Name accordingly

```
function remapDataName(arr, dataName){
  let s = [...arr] // 
  console.log(s)
  console.log(dataName)

  dataName.forEach(function(val, counter = 0){
    counter = 0
    s.forEach(function(data){
      if(data["name"] == val){
        data["name"] += "(" + counter++ + ")"
      }
    })
  })
  return s
}
```

call those functions

```
let objectName = getAllDataName(array)
let objectNameMapped = remapDataName(array, objectName)
```

objectNameMapped will print

```
[
  { name: 'TV(0)', price: 12323, id: 321 },
  { name: 'Kettle(0)', price: 123, id: 1211 },
  { name: 'TV(1)', price: 3434, id: 3434312 },
  { name: 'Car(0)', price: 12343, id: 123123123 },
  { name: 'TV(2)', price: 4554, id: 2313123123311 }
]
```